# How to achieve this layout in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been playing around with grids but I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this layout? My concern is the textbox on the bottom right... in a table, I'd do a `rowspan=2` but I'm not sure if I can do the equivalent using Bootstrap's grid structure.

Furthermore, I've had some trouble getting the checkbox to be vertically aligned - with the text/label for the checkbox also vertically aligned.

Any thought - on either of those points - would be warmly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a grid to display a table?

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1mz1Lrug/

Comment: Add a fiddle and what you have so far code wise.

Comment: Thanks @Abhitalks - that was what I was trying to achieve, particularly with the checkbox being vertically aligned.